# How to Submit Java Swing App to the Mac App Store

Tags: java, macos, app-store

Apple Store requires the use of an embedded JRE as a prerequisite for Mac App Store distribution.

OpenJDK or Oracle JRE, Allows Oracle distribute its JRE?

My Java Swing Application is Already packaged in a .app file, do I have to do something else before uploading my application to sanbox apple?

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle's Ant-based tool `appbundler`.  With it, you can specify a runtime to add to your app:

```
<runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}" />
```

See the following guide for more details: [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html)

Comment: OpenJDK or Oracle JRE, Allows Oracle distribute its JRE?

Comment: Yes, I read that in your original question, but I don't know what you are asking.  Typically, one would include only the JRE in an app.  JDK is for development.  The guide I linked to explains it clearly: see [Bundle the JRE with the App Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html#bundle_jre)

Comment: Wow! I had not realized an app. bundler had been around for *that* long!